# Any use for the interactive flare on the Title Screen of Spelunky Classic?

Tags: spelunky

In Spelunky Classic, there's a flare on the title screen. I can throw on the words, but is there some use other than just for fun?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you let the opening cinematic play completely, you'll see that the flare is dropped on purpose by the Spelunker to light up the cave as he climbs down. For consistency's sake, since you take control of the character right after the cinematic, the flare remains, which means you can pick it up and throw it.

Since you can't bring it with into a new game or a shortcut, it's only "functional" purpose is to be entertaining on the title screen.